# How can I move an object on a plane of two axis like XY?

Tags: 3d-view, transforms

Is it possible to move an object in the 3D View on a plane of two axis like XY, XZ, YZ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By pressing <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, while you're grabbing (<kbd>G</kbd>), the operator will constrain the movement in that axis. So <kbd>G</kbd> then <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> will just move the selection in the XY plane.