# How do I limit scaling in 2 directions?

Tags: transforms

I would like to enlarge the hole of this model.
To do that, I have selected some vertices, then I used Scaling.

However, I need to avoid scaling in the z direction, else it looks like shown on the right.

How could I do that?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Instead of pressing S then Z to limit scaling to the Z axis, you have to use Shift+Z, this locks the Z axis and scales only on X and Y.

Comment: Thank you very much. That helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Just for it to be answered properly for people to find it in the future:
Press S for scale.
Press Shift+Z or X or Y to lock it on the respective two axes.
Also: works as well with moving and rotation.

Comment: Well, I thought there are already enough answers on how to lock certain axes. This one for example: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74455/ but I just didn't bother to mark it as duplicate.